# ANTLR 4 IDE strange <.> symbol in parse tree

Tags: translation, antlr4

I'm trying to create sort of css preprocessor for my study. 
This is my grammar. It does a little for now, but it already doesn't work.

```
grammar CSSS;

@header {
    package antlr;
}

program
    : member*
    ;

member
    : element
    ;

element
    : selector '{' property* '}'
    ;

selector
    : selector_atom (('>'|'+'|'~') selector_atom)*
    ;

selector_atom
    : ('#'|'.')? NAME
    | '*'
    ;

property
    : prop_name ':' prop_value+ ';' 
    ;

prop_name
    : NAME
    ;

prop_value
    : (CSSLETTER | NUMBER)+ 
    ;

NAME: CSSLETTER+;
NUMBER: '0'..'9';
CSSLETTER: 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '-' | '_'; 
WS: (' '|'\n'|'\r'|'\t'|'\f')+ { skip(); };
```

Problem is when i try to feed it with this input

```
body {
    font-size: 19px;
    ...
}
```

parse tree outputs this [strange dot symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3i2uH.jpg) where it should skip whitespace.
Can someone please explain what is this thing and how to make everything work fine.

Comment: How do you feed the input to your parser? Are you using some kind of plugin (ANTLRv4 for IntelliJ), IDE (ANTLRWorks2) or you just generated parser/lexer from this grammar and use it in your program?

Comment: As header says, i'm using ANTLR 4 IDE (it's a plugin for eclipse). It has live interpreter, where one can print some input and get a parse tree as an output.

Comment: Just change `{ skip(); }` to `-> skip;`